# SDL2 Texture Render target doesn't have alpha transparency

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl-2

I've encountered a problem while programming on C with SDL2. I have rendered to a texture simple images of squares that are transparent in the center. But when I draw the texture on which they are rendered they are not see-through. I've tried even changing the transparency of the rendered texture with SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod() but it isn't changing anything. If I change the alpha on the  textures that are being rendered(the squares). They get dimmer but still they cover anything behind them. So I'm open to suggestions.
This is an image where I have lowered the alpha on the squares textueres:https://i.stack.imgur.com/46HAz.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two methods in SDL2 if you want to have a transparent image:

1. (Static Method)

   Use an image editing software and directly change the alpha value there, it will carry on to SDL2.
2. (Dynamic Method)

   ```
   // This sets the texture in blendmode.
   SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

   // This section should be where you alter the alpha. 
   // You can make fade in-fade out effects, etc... Just put the changes here.
   Uint8 alpha = 0x7F; 

   // Sets the alpha into the texture.
   SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(texture, alpha); 

   // Redraws the image with a fresh, new alpha.
   SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
   ```

Comment: Ok thanks. It worked when I set the blend mode to  SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND. Method one wasn't an option for me because the texture was runtime generated through rendering on top of it.